# Ruby on Rails: replace backslashes except in \a \b \c ... \n ... \t .... \z

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am looking for an Regex to replace backslashes to double backslashes except involved in '\a' '\b' '\c' ... '\n' ... '\t' .... '\uXXXX' '\xHH' '\z' sequences. Could you help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Maybe a few examples would help. Plus the golden oldie: What did you try?

Comment: It sounds like you're storing partially escaped data. You should worry about fixing that, rather than continuing to use bad data.

Comment: @meagar: Yes, that is the point! Data must be partially escaped out of two reasons: 1. There must be a means to enter newline, tab etc into a single-line INPUT (it is why I can't unescape all the data), but user shouldn't be bothered entering escaped symbols all the way, just in places where escaped symbols are unavoidable (it is obvious that he can easily forget to escape the apostrophe or backslash); 2. the application should export data to 2 different platforms where escaping rules differ;

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
/\\[^a-z]?/
```

If you want a precise list:

```
/\\[^abcntuz]?/
```

Comment: That matches `\1` including the 1, and it matches the `\` in `\a`. I'm not sure what the question really is, but that doesn't sound like it.

Comment: I tried this: puts a.gsub(/\\[^a-z]?/, '\\\\') and it didn't work. It replaced only when I added two more slashes: puts a.gsub(/\\[^a-z]?/, '\\\\\\') and replaced all the slashes.